# Plot graph with custom axes

Tags: mathematica, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

How to plot graph with custom axes in Mathematica 8.0?

e.g. use the axes $\frac1y$ instead of $y$ and $x^2$ instead of $x$?

this is to implement Linear Law

Answer (score 5):

Instead of plotting $f(x)$ just plot $f(x^2)$ or $1/f(x)$ and change the labeling of the axes :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(f[x_]) := 2 x^2 + 3;
ParametricPlot[{x^2, f[x]}, {x, 0, 3.5}]
```

Comment: It would help improve your answer if you also explained in words the idea you're trying to demonstrate.